# software collections building a perl526 program

Tags: software-collections

I'm looking to see if there is a best practice for building a perl526 program using   scl perl526.

I'll be using git clone to pull the source code in, and then building it with scl rh-perl526 enable bash

Would I git clone into /opt/rh/rh-perl526/root/opt or is it better placed elsewhere?

The program I'm building is https://github.com/Ensembl/ensembl-vep.git and it builds quite nicely, but has various optional things to add.

The end program needs to be accessible to all users once built.

Thank you

Bryan